# AWS API Gateway dynamic url configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, api-gateway

I'm new to AWS, I have been asked a question `"API Gateway URL is dynamic and keep changing, so how do you handle this situation and what URL you will share with Client?"`. I have googled for possible answers but couldn't find any relevant answers to this question, please do let me know if this is a right question or just asked me to confuse?

Answer (score 0):

The URL depends on the id of the API Gateway instance: once you've created the API gateway, it gets an id and such id does not change (even if you keep updating and modifying it).

Anyway, if you aim at associating a "nice" domain name with your API gateway, you're looking for what is called a `Custom domain name`: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html